# In Ruby with Selenium, difficulty programmatically sending the ENTER key

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Ruby with Selenium, I am having difficulty programmatically sending the ENTER key.

I manage to programmatically load up google.com in Firefox and send keys into the search box.

I can manually hit ENTER, that works, but I want to programmatically hit ENTER. And my attempts at programmatically hitting ENTER haven't worked.

Here's the loading the page and entering text into the search box. That works:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'selenium-webdriver'
=> true

irb(main):002:0> driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:firefox
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Marionette::Driver:0x..fb3c81796cc82b708 browser=:firefox>

irb(main):003:0> driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com")
=> nil

irb(main):004:0> inps=driver.find_elements(:tag_name, "input");
=> [#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..fbd90f502ff3e0576 id="534cf85c-1315-994f-ba72-0eae5f6ada73">, #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x2c3d35f89c794

irb(main):080:0> driver.find_element(:name, "q").send_keys("abab");
=> nil
```

So, that above all works fine and puts text into the search box.

Now for programmatically hitting ENTER:

```
driver.find_element(:name, "q").send_keys("\n"); 

driver.find_element(:name, "q").send_keys("aaa\n"); 

driver.action.send_keys("\n").perform
```

And each of those three lines with `\u0006` instead of `\n`.

And each of those three lines with `\u0007` instead of `\n`.

It's not working.

The `\n` has no visual effect. And the `\u0006` and `\u0007` just make the special character appear in the textbox.

I tried sending to the body instead:

```
irb(main):087:0> b=driver.find_element(:tag_name, "body")
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x45552f31d66411fa id="ce2a065b-c12a-1740-82ee-68bcf8a43ead">
irb(main):088:0> b.send_key("\n");
=> nil
irb(main):089:0> b.send_key("\n");
=> nil
irb(main):090:0> b.send_key("\u0006");
=> nil
irb(main):091:0> b.send_keys("\u0007");
=> nil
irb(main):092:0> b.send_keys("\n");
```

[image]

And it's the same issue. `\u` makes the character appear in the box. `\n` has no visual effect. And neither of them are sending an ENTER as a manual push of the ENTER key would.

Comment: Hi, If you are ready to use Ruby Selenium Binding, then use WATIR which is a nice wrapper around Ruby Selenium Binding, there are plenty of other things which are added in WATIR which would not be available to you if you use Ruby Selenium Binding.

Comment: @Rajagopalan thanks I think I will try that some time

Comment: Sure, here is a guide for you http://watir.com/guides/

Comment: useful send_keys documentation https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium%2FWebDriver%2FElement%3Asend_keys . I see a list of key codes  https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Keys#KEYS-constant . And also listed https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/keys.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code for hitting the "ENTER" key:

```
driver.find_element(:name, "q").send_keys:return
```

Comment: and this `driver.find_element(:name, "q").send_keys "fff","a",:return;` (to send fffa<ENTER>)

Comment: useful page has all codes listed https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Keys#KEYS-constant

Answer (score -1):

Try it with `\ue007`:

```
driver.find_element(:name, "q").send_keys("\ue007");
```

Edit: as it is probably not really obvious, the code I am proposing is different from what you have tried. It has an additional "e" character, which makes it a totally different unicode code.

Also, if you check selenium source - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/keys.rb - this code - `\ue007`, is what is defined as the return key. And calling `send_keys:return` sends exactly this code.

HTH.

Comment: when I realised re the 'e' (minutes ago),  I couldn't undo it without editing your question.. but i've added a note now to your question that is much clearer. And I have now upvoted it. So it has gone from -2 to 0.

Comment: thanks, and for the record, I notice `\ue006`(return) works too.. though indeed I asked for 'enter', which is, as you say, `\ue007`(enter)

Comment: Side note - the two in fact are different keys, and characters (as you've seen in selenium's code table); this is a leftover from the "good old days" in the computing. The good thing is browsers handle them the same, e.g. in a way unify them in the same operation.